# Edit a <completed> Contribution donation

Tags: contributions, recurring-contributions, donations

i have a customer who wants to enter past contributions and it's not recording the `<Date Received>`.

Once completed, it shows a 0 value in the date received and it's not allowing me to go back and edit the contribution because no save button is showing

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: have you compared to eg drupal.demo.civicrm.org?

Comment: Entering past contributions with arbitrary date received is definitely something that CiviCRM should be able to do. There's likely something specific about your setup that is causing issues.